# Spring Hibernate JPA HSQL Table not found in statement

Tags: spring, jpa, hsqldb

I'm training Spring persistence with LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean and getting error:

```
 Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Table not found in statement [insert into PERSON      (ID, email, name) values (null, ?, ?)]
```

Don't really know what I did wrong

My Main class (for test only)

```
    package com.me.test;

    import com.me.model.Person;
    import com.me.service.PersonService;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.logging.Logger;
    import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
    import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

    public class Main {

    /**
     *
     */
    public static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName());
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        log.info("************** BEGINNING PROGRAM **************");

        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("WEB-INF/spring-config.xml");
        PersonService personService = (PersonService) context.getBean("personService");

        Person person = new Person();
        person.setName("name");
        person.setEmail("name@name.com");
        personService.addPerson(person);
        log.info("Person : " + person + " added successfully");

        List<Person> persons = personService.fetchAllPersons();
        log.info("The list of all persons = " + persons);

        log.info("************** ENDING PROGRAM *****************");
    }
}
```

My application context:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx  
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.me" />

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:META-INF/persistence.xml" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="personPersistenceUnit" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter" />
        <property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jpaVendorAdapter"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
        <property name="database" value="HSQL" />
        <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jpaDialect" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect" />

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:file:/home/me/Pulpit/hsql1/db3; shutdown=true" />
        <property name="username" value="sa" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="dbUtil" class="com.me.service.DbUtil">
<!--        init-method="initialize">-->
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

</beans> 

persistence.xml:

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    version="1.0">
        <persistence-unit name="personPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL" >
            <class>com.me.model.Person</class>
        </persistence-unit>
    </persistence>
```

PersonService class

```
package com.me.service;

import com.me.dao.PersonDao;
import com.me.model.Person;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class PersonService {

    private PersonDao personDao;

    public PersonDao getPersonDao() {
        return personDao;
    }
    @Autowired
    public void setPersonDao(PersonDao personDao) {
        this.personDao = personDao;
    }

    public void addPerson(Person person) {
        getPersonDao().insert(person);
    }

    public List<Person> fetchAllPersons() {
        return getPersonDao().selectAll();
    }
}
```

personDAO class

```
package com.me.dao;

import com.me.model.Person;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Propagation;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Repository("personDao")
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public class PersonDao {

    private static final String SELECT_QUERY = "select p from Person p";

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return entityManager;
    }

    public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    public void insert(Person person) {
        entityManager.persist(person);
    }

    public List<Person> selectAll() {
        Query query = entityManager.createQuery(SELECT_QUERY);
        List<Person> persons = (List<Person>) query.getResultList();
        return persons;
    }

}
```

What's wrong here guys?

edit:
adding person class:

```
package com.me.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSON")
public class Person implements Serializable{

    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String email;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "ID")
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", email=" + email + "]";
    }

}
```

and persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    version="1.0">
    <persistence-unit name="personPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL" >
    <class>com.me.model.Person</class>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: Is your `Person` class annotated with `@Entity` ?

Comment: see question edition above :)

Comment: Could you also show `persistence.xml`?

Comment: sure - question updated

Comment: Check out my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have not told Hibernate anywhere that it needs to create the tables when it loads.

An easy way to do that would be to add

`<properties>
         <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
 </properties>`

inside `persistence.xml` after `<class>`

Comment: yes it worked! Thank you. To be more specific in persistence.xml file I had to create <properties> element and put the <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/> inside.